# How to display product details (Angular/Firebase)?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

**Data** `product.model.ts`

```
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  price_solde: number;
  description: string;
  fichetech: string;
  imageURL: string[];
  category: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

**Creating a file** `product.service.ts`
The last function `getDetailProduct(productId: string)` to get a product by its ID

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductsService {

    productCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
    
    constructor(private dbstore: AngularFirestore) {
      this.productCollection = this.dbstore.collection('products', (ref) => 
        ref.orderBy('name', 'desc')
      );
    }

    addProduct = (product: Product) => this.productCollection.add(product);


    getProducts() {
      return this.dbstore.collection('products').snapshotChanges();
    }

    getDetailProduct(productId: string): Observable<Product | undefined> {
      return this.productCollection.doc(productId).valueChanges();
    }

}
```

**Call the function in the `product.service.ts` service to be able to access the product details page with its ID.**

```
  goToDetailsProduct(productId?: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['product-details', productId]);
    console.log(productId);
  }
```

**If we click on a product, the link that should come with its ID in the URL**

```
<div class="card card-shopping" *ngFor="let product of products" (click)="goToDetailsProduct(product.id)">
```

**Problem: How to retrieve all product data and display it on the page `details-product.component.ts`?**

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product.model';
import { ProductsService } from '../../shared/services/products.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-product',
  templateUrl: './details-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details-product.component.css']
})
export class DetailsProductComponent implements OnInit {

  productIdRoute?: string;
  product?: Observable<Product | undefined>;

  constructor(
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private productService: ProductsService
  ) {
    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    this.productIdRoute = String(routeParams.get('productId'))
    this.product = this.productService.getDetailProduct(this.productIdRoute);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // goBack = () => this.location.back();

}
```

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing ? do you have an error thrown ? no error thrown but details are not displayed ? for displaying the details you should just async pipe the product observable in the template (by the way, the convention for naming observables is observableName$, so, with a dollar symbol at the end of the name)

Comment: To view product data by ID

Comment: your comment is not really helping clarifying your scenario. It would be very helpful if you would replicate your scenario in a stackblitz instance and share the link for it with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from yoir question is that you want to display the detailed data in a component and you are passing ID in a URL.
To retrieve the data, you can use 2 scenarios:

1. In the detail, call the firebase function for getting a single data instance

In your constructor, you need to initialze the Route parameter object as:

```
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
```

In your on init method, add this code

```
this.route.params.subscribe(() => {this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];});
//id indicates the query parameter name. you can replace it with your provided query parameter name.
```

From the above steps you will get the ID through parameter. Now you need to call firebase function to get the instance:

```
this.afs.collection('collection_name')
  .doc(id)
  .ref;
```

2. You can also pass the data through Route parameters
   In your products page, pass the data as

   ```
     this.router.navigate(['/about'], {
      state: {
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Angular', detail: '1' })}
    });
   ```

Then in your detail page, you can use

```
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
      this.routeState = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
  if (this.routeState) {
    this.data.frontEnd = this.routeState.frontEnd ? JSON.parse(this.routeState.data) : '';
    this.data.site = this.routeState.site ? this.routeState.site : '';
  }
}}
```

i suggest you to go with the first one becuase it is easy to work with.

Comment: You understood what I really want.
Yes, I would love a code explanation of my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: i edited my answer. please check.